# What is the best way to share assets - icons/images - across multiple Flex applications?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, swc

I am in the process of creating a new - "lite" - version of a Flex application I created a while ago. I have been porting over many of the Classes and Components to a Flex Library Project that compiles an SWC file. Because both are Cairngorm applications, I'm not able to completely eradicate duplicate code, but it seems logical that I should be able to share assets - such as icons (PNG files). What is the best way to do this? I have tried including them in the SWC, but I can't figure out how to access them in the application. If you can help me figure that out, then my question will be answered. Any thoughts?

Here is and example of how I currently embed icons/images in my Flex application:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/icons/cancelIcon.png")]
        private var cancelIcon:Class;

        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/icons/saveIcon.png")]
        private var saveIcon:Class;
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0) First, looking at the code above - I recommend some minor changes:

```
// Actionscript instead of MXML:
public class ResourceClasses
{
        Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/icons/cancelIcon.png")]
        public static var CancelIconClass:Class;

        // make your variable public and static without public no one 
        // outside the class can access AND bindable won't matter
}
```

---- Now, compile your library.
---- If the assets aren't in the right place the compiler will complain

1) In your application, you need to reference the library project / swc

---- You should be able to get code hints / intellisense in Flex Builder / eclipse from classes in your Application to classes in the library project

2) In your Application - Do some code like this:

```
var image:Image = new Image();
image.source = ResourceClasses.CancelIconClass;

// more image property setting... 

someCanvas.addChild(image);
```

3) This will get you going - using a Library project to hold images, etc...

*** DO NOTE: If the images need to be loaded multiple times, reused, etc -- There are other steps to take to squeeze out the best performance, etc...

Comment: Thanks. The code above was simply showing how I embed the images right in the app without the use of a library. I think I get what your saying - I actually started thinking something exactly along these lines last night in bed. The icons are stored as Classes, so I can embed them in the library and reference them as Classes, instead of embedding them in my with a URL. What performance tips can you give me?

Comment: Sadly, out of comment space had to edit down.<br/>Might be a topic for a new question as others no doubt have a ton to add RE: Resources and performance in Flex).<br/>In short, see from Adobe: http://tinyurl.com/nwe4yo and http://tinyurl.com/dlvjr3 - check out how to organize your web-app with RSLs to avoid bring the entire application down at once & making the user wait.<br/>Also see cool code-level techniques for re-using resources at runtime efficiently in the ASDocs on BitmapAsset @ http://tinyurl.com/muy8do

Answer (score 0):

This section of the livedocs would be interesting to you:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=building_overview_5.html.

Do you have a specific example of how you are embedding the assets and trying to use them in the resulting swc that isn't working? Do you think your problem is in the embedding them into the swc or using them from the swc in the actual application?

Comment: I have no problem adding the assets to the library project and then building the SWC. It's also no problem referencing the SWC, and other Classes in the SWC. I just don't know how to access the assets from the SWC in my Flex Application.

Comment: can you give an example of what you have tried and it did not work? Are you embedding the assets and associating them with a class variable? If so, can you not just reference that variable in the end application? I'm just thinking that a concrete example would help clarify.

Comment: example added to original question above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using @Gabriel's advice, here's what I ended up with:

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public class ResourceClasses
    {
        [Embed(source="assets/icons/cross.png")]
        public static var CancelIconClass:Class;
    }
}
```

Referenced in my application like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Button label="Cancel Changes" icon="{ResourceClasses.CancelIconClass}" />
</mx:Box>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff - If you find that you need to reuse the cancel icon or other images over and over again - be sure to check out BitmapAsset - if you need a little help there - fire up a question - happy to help.

Comment: Oh - noted some URLs about performance in comments in the original answer.

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Since your icons are all from the SWC file, what does this path `[Embed(source="assets/icons/cross.png")]` mean?